# EF Core: Remove accidentally created column in migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, migration

I use Entity Framework Core 2.1 and accidentally created two columns for a navigation property of a 1:n relationship a long time ago. The second column is not needed and I want to remove it. These columns are already used by others, so I might have to use another migration to get rid of it.

#### Code

These are my entity classes with the relevant configuration.

```
public class MailReceiver
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public MailTemplate MailTemplate { get; set; }
    public long? MailTemplateId { get; set; }
}
public class MailTemplate
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MailReceiver> Receivers { get; set; }
}
//Fluent API
public static void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<MailReceiver>()
        .HasKey(p => p.Id);

    builder.Entity<MailReceiver>()
       .HasOne(f => f.MailTemplate)
       .WithMany()
       .HasForeignKey(t => t.MailTemplateId)
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
       .IsRequired(true);
}
```

With these settings a "MailTemplateId" and a "MailTemplateId1" column was created on the MailReceiver table. For both columns there is an index and a foreign key constraint to "MailTemplate" -> Id. Note: There is no "MailTemplateId1" or "MailTemplate1" property in the MailReceiver class and no configuration for such a column. Obviously I don't need the "MailTemplateId1" column.

#### What I tried

- Just executing `Add-Migration` results in an empty migration.
- Changing `long?` to `long` for the MailTemplateId results in an empty migration.
- Edits in the ModelSnapshot class are reverted when adding the next migration.
- Manually creating a migration to remove the column, the index and the foreign key removes it in the database after `Update-Database` but SQL generated by EF Core for queries still uses the column which results in an error. It is readded with the next migration automatically.
- Going back to the migration creating the columns is not an option. The database is already used elsewhere.
- Changes in the Fluent API configuration such as stated below result in an empty migration.

  ```
  builder.Entity<MailTemplate>()
           .HasMany(m => m.Receivers)
           .WithOne(m => m.MailTemplate)
           .HasForeignKey(m => m.MailTemplateId);

  builder.Entity<MailReceiver>()
          .HasOne(f => f.MailTemplate)
          .WithMany(f => f.Receivers)
          .HasForeignKey(t => t.MailTemplateId)
          .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
          .IsRequired(true);
  ```

#### How can I get rid of the MailTemplateId1 column and use the right MailTemplateId column for all generated queries from now on?

Bonus: Why was the second column created in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to accomplish what you want, is to add the other side (the "many" side) to the navigation:

```cs
builder.Entity<MailReceiver>()
    .HasOne(f => f.MailTemplate)
    .WithMany(t => t.Receivers) // <-- add t.Receivers
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.MailTemplateId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
    .IsRequired(true);
```

This will result in the following `UP()` being generated when adding another migration:

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
        name: "FK_MailReceivers_MailTemplates_MailTemplateId1",
        table: "MailReceivers");

    migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
        name: "IX_MailReceivers_MailTemplateId1",
        table: "MailReceivers");

    migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
        name: "MailTemplateId1",
        table: "MailReceivers");
}
```

If you don't want to use the `MailTemplate.Receivers` collection for navigation, then you need to either remove it from the model class, or ignore it:

```cs
builder.Entity<MailTemplate>()
    .Ignore(p => p.Receivers);
```

Otherwise, EF Core will use it as a navigation property by convention and will add the missing foreign key for it as a shadow property (resulting in the `MailTemplateId1` column).